# MSEP and R2pred for Linear Model

Tags: predictive-models, linear-model, prediction, lm, rms

I have two set of data 1-Training (Calibrating) 2-Test. With these datasets, I

- Fit the model using first dataset.
- predict using the second dataset x-variables
- I have to test the closeness of the prediction
- In pls package, I can using following command to calculate `RMSEP` and `R2`,

  `predict(my.pls.model, newdata=my.new.data, nc=component.i.need)`

However, I need the same thing for linear model. I found a package called `mixlm`, but this can only calculate `RMSEP` or `R2pred` for the first set, i.e. prediction made with calibration dataset not the test set. Is there some formula or function that I can use to calculate `RMSE` or `R2pred` for linear model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the `pls` package documentation, you'll find that `R2` and `RMSEP` are described ([here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/pls/docs/mvrVal)). The documentation provides also a reference to [Melvik and Rene (2004)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cem.887/abstract). Those two sources combined tell you that:

$$R^2 = 1 - \frac{SSE}{SST}$$

where $SST = \sum^n_{i=1} (y_i - \overline{y})^2 $ and $SSE = \sum^n_{i=1} (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2 $. And MSEP is:

$$MSEP_{\text{test}} = \frac{1}{n_T} \sum^{n_T}_{i=1} \left( \hat{y}_{T,i} - y_{T,i} \right)^2 $$

that is computed over $T$ test sets, each of size $n_T$, where $\hat{y}_{T,i}$ an estimate computed on test set $T$.

In R that would be something like:

```
y_hat <- predict(model)
sst <- sum((y - mean(y))^2)
sse <- sum((y - y_hat)^2)
r_sq <- 1 - (sse/sst)
msep_T <- sum((y_hat - y)^2) / n
```

Reading [Melvik and Rene (2004)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cem.887/abstract) paper would give you hints how to adapt this code to your needs (e.g. to apply it to different test-sets or cross-validation sets).

However, notice also what does authors of `pls` say about $R^2$:

> For R2, this is the unadjusted $R^2$. It is overoptimistic and should
>   not be used for assessing models.